# Flutter Codemagic Static Pages failed without any error

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, codemagic

I try to build my flutter app for web with Codemagic. But the publish failed every time.

On my pc it works without any problems and Codemagic also worked till one week ago.

Here the output of Codemagic:

[image]

I see no reason why it failed.

Any ideas?

I disabled the Publish step and then it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately there was a bug in gcloud utils which Codemagic uses internally to publish web apps.

The team prepared a fix and it was deployed. So the publishing should work as expected.

=== BEFORE UDATE ===

There is also a workaround you can switch to Xcode 13.2 virtual machine that not affected by the gcloud issue.

Comment: I'm afraid this still seems to happening as of today, using the Linux X2 VM.

Comment: @Maks thank you for reporting this, we have found another issue on Linux instances and it was fixed now. Can you give it another try?

Comment: thanks Mikhail! Yes the deploy step succeeds now but the deployed app doesn't seem to work correctly in comparison to the same build being deployed and working correctly on Firebase hosting. I'll look into it more and take up the discussion on CM's slack.